# RAILS before_save callback of parent object runs before the associated child object is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class Car and a class Part which looks like below. Both these classes have an attribute 'price'. Now the price of Car is sum of all part prices. Also, in case there is a Part without a price, i.e. if the price of one or more parts of the car is nil, then the price of the Car is set to nil.

```
Class Car 
  has_many :parts
  before_save :calculate_price

  private
  def calculate_price
    # calculate the price of car by summing all parts prices.
  end
end

Class Part
  belongs_to :car, inverse_of: parts
end
```

**Problem**

Whenever the price of a part is changed, I want to recalculate the price of the Car. Now for this I added a before_save callback, but the callback runs before the parts objects are saved and when I do `self.parts` it load the parts objects from database instead of loading them from memory and hence I don't get the updated value of price. How do I make the before_save to run after the associated child objects have been saved OR load the child objects from memory?

Comment: Not tested - but try changing the association to **belongs_to :car, inverse_of: parts, touch: true**. [more information](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to put a callback into the `Part` model, since you want to react to price changes of the parts, right? Something like:

```
class Part
  before_save :update_car_price

  def update_car_price
    self.car.touch if self.car.present?
  end
end
```

Not tested, but I think `touch` should be enough and you won't have to expose the `calculate_price` of `Car`.

Warning: This might get really ugly if you do lots of price updates on cars and parts.